# Access Subform Datasheet Only Returning 1 Result

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I know this question has been asked multiple times in some form or fashion, but I'm not been able to find a solution that works and it's driving me crazy. I'm creating a search form in Access that executes a select query via VBA to find data that is in a table. So far this has been pretty straight forward, the query works, and the form returns results. The issue is that I'm using a subform to return/display the results and it is only returning one result at a time.

I used the setup wizard to add the subform to the main form and I linked the two forms during that process. I have the subform being displayed as a datasheet, but even if I change it to a "continuous form" it still just returns one record at a time. I have my subform's `Record Source` set as my Select query (`Select * From tbl_Search`)  , and I've set the `Record Source` for my main form to just about anything I can think of (Select query, table, nothing...).

I know there has to be a way to return all the records in one datasheet without having to continuously click the next arrow, but I have yet to figure out what that way is.

Since this isn't an issue with the code per se, I wasn't sure what kind of images or code blocks might be necessary to answer this question, so i tried to be as descriptive as possible. If there is a chunk of code or screenshot that you need to help answer this question, just let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Your main form should be unbound. Create a search query and set it as the subform's recordsource. You can pass the main form's fields as parameters to the query, for example:

```
PARAMETERS [Forms]![YourMainForm]![YourTextField] Text (255);
SELECT *
FROM YourTableName
WHERE ((([FieldName)=[Forms]![YourMainForm]![YourTextField]));
```

The only thing you have to do when running a search is to `.Requery` the subform.

```
Me.SubformName.Form.Requery
```

Comment: Thanks  for the help, but I'm still having some issues. Right now I have `SELECT * FROM tbl_Search WHERE ((Form_Name Like ""*" & [Forms]![Program Search]![strsearch] & "*""))` as my search query inside my subform. In my subform's `Record Source` I have a simple `Select * from tbl_Search`.  In my main form I have `Me.SubformName.form.requery` and I get an error of  `Method or data member not found` and it highlights my subform name when I try and run the program.

Comment: You need to change `SubformName` to the actual name of the subform control.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. I am using the actual subform name, I just used SubformName in the `Me.SubformName` example because it was in your answer. Was trying to keep my comment consistent with the example.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean the search query is "inside my subform". The search query should be set as the recordsource of the subform in design >> properties >> data `Record Source = Query Name`. So you have only one query as the subform's recordsource and nothing else. When you click the button in main form you just requery the subform.