# MS Access query with parameter from combobox in form does not return any results

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameters, combobox

I have created an MS Access database with several tables and queries but the problem described further down is about the following:

- *tEmployee* table contains employee data as the name implies.
- *tCases* table contains data about court cases.
- Each case can be assigned to only one employee. I have created a relationship from `[tCases]![assignedTo]` field to *tEmployee*.
- *fSearches* is a form to perform searches among the cases. It includes a combobox *cEmployee* which is populated from `[tEmployee].[surname]` and a command button to perform the search.

**GOAL**: to select employee in `[fSearches]![cEmployee]`, hit the button and show all the cases assigned to this employee in another form named *fResultsCases*.

This is the code for the button where lines in comments are some of the things I've tried:

```
If cEmploee.ListIndex = -1 Then
     MsgBox "You have to select employee to perform search.", title:="Missing value!"
Else
     tHidden2.SetFocus
     tHidden2.Text = "assigned to " & cEmploee & "."
     DoCmd.OpenForm "fResultsCases"

     'Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE [tCases]![assignedTo] like [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"

     'Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE tCases .[assignedTo] = [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"

     Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE [assignedTo] = [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"

     Forms("fResultsCases").Recalc
End If
```

With all the above mentioned I get the following:

- `[fResultsCases]` opens but does not return any case.
- I tried to omit the `WHERE` clause and `[fResultsCases]` returns all cases as expected.
- Then I tried to narrow things down to understand the problem by creating a simple query with one parameter and got exactly the same results.

  ```sql
  SELECT tCases.[case number], tCases.subject, tCases.fromDt, tCases.toDt, 
         tCases.assignedTo, tCases.[date assigned], tCases.[date completed]
  FROM tCases
  WHERE (((tCases.assignedTo)=[Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee]));
  ```

It seems like I'm missing something about the `WHERE` clause when it comes to combobox values but I can't figure it out. I am new to MS Access. Any help will be very appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

*cEmploee rowsource property*:  `SELECT [tEmployee].surname FROM tEmployee ORDER BY [surname];`

*cEmploee bound column property*:  1

Comment: If `[surname]` is text, you need to enclose the value in `'` single quotes.

Comment: See the answer in this post, it might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147117/access-subform-datasheet-only-returning-1-result/47151963#47151963

Comment: @Parfait That's true but I was referring to the recordSource' sql in code example.

Comment: @Kostas K. I tried your solution but it did not change anything. But I discovered sth strange (to me). Although [assignedTo] was text in the begining, when I connected it with the table tEmployee, it's data type changed to number and I don't know why. [tEmployee]![surname] IS text though. You think this causes some kind of problem?

Comment: Does tCases' *assignedTo* correspond to tEmployee's *Surname*? You might have a lookup field. Open the tCases table and try chainging any value in *assignedTo*. Does a dropdown appear in table (not any form)?

Comment: @Parfait: That's exactly the case: *assignedTo* corresponds to tEmployee's *Surname* and a dropdown appears in table when trying to change some value in this field.

Comment: Then you have a lookup field. Simplest instructions: delete current combobox, create a new combobox with same control name as previous but this time follow entire pop-up Wizard selecting *Remember value for later* option at end which by default bounds a hidden ID field. Then use same SQL with `WHERE assignedTo = [combobox]` in line with my answer below.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time. Just one last question. While in form design view, I insert a combobox. What Wizard should appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After about ten days of "struggle" with this brainteaser, I decided to post this question to ask for help. Fortunatelly @Parfait has involved with my problem and with his/her accurate remarks helped me understand my mistakes. It also helped me [Ken Sheridan's post here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_2013_release/changing-the-datatype-from-short-text-to-lookup/6d9b76f9-c007-4410-b46e-0d62628ab149). So I am posting my answer just for future reference. @Parfait, I sincerely thank you for your time.

So the problem in this case was primarily understanding how relationships between tables affect data types. If you want to connect a *textfield* of *tableA* to *tableB*, then there are two cases. If the primary key in *tableB* is number then *textfield* becomes number. If the primary key in *tableB* is text then *textfield* remains text.

In my case it was the first one. Specifically the field `[tCases]![assignedTo]` after creating relationship with table `[tEmployee]`, was turned automatically into number *(It still shows the surname but contains the corresponding primary key in tEmployee)*. On the contrary combobox `[cEmploee]` still contained text. This why this line:

```
Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE [assignedTo] = [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"
```

was not returning any record as @Parfait successfully guessed.

---

At this point there were two possible solutions:

**1) Set surname as primary key to agree with combobox contents.**

- delete the relationship between `[tCases]![assignedTo]` and `[tEmployee]`.
- set field `[tEmployee]![surname]` (which **is** text) as primary key in table `[tEmployee]`.
- create a new relationship between `[tCases]![assignedTo]` and `[tEmployee]`.

I did not try this solution though, as a problem would occur if 2 employees had the same surname. So I suggest following the second.

**2) Keep the same primary key and use it to match the records from tableA to the surname from tableB.**

To achieve this you have to inform access, that you want the records from tableA that have the ID, while in tableB this ID corresponds to the surname inserted in the combobox (hope this makes sense). In other words create a recordset of both tables (union query). For this purpose I replaced the above refered line of code with the following:

```
Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT tCases.* FROM tCases INNER JOIN tEmployee ON tCases.[assignedTo] = tEmployee.[employeeID] " & _
"WHERE tEmployee.[surname]=[Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee] AND tCases![assignedTo]=[tEmployee]![employeeID];"
```

Hope this saves some time from other people. Have a nice day!

Comment: You can also convert data types in queries to make them "work" as well. Its kind of dirty but in shitty situations it useful to know that you can work around it kind of.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot recreate your issue replicating your setup with combox that triggers an update of form's recordsource. And because neither an error is raised nor parameter input prompt appears, likely the `WHERE` clause is returning `False` (i.e., no matching records) and hence no rows are returned.

The reason can likely be due to the  combobox *[Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee]* which **show** Employee's surname but is **bound** to the unique ID as the default setup of Access' comboboxes (if using wizard). See *Data* tab of combobox's properties in Design View.

The reason for this hidden bound field is users never know the unique ID of a record but do know the value (i.e., name). So when they select the recognized name they are really selecting the corresponding unique ID. Therefore, consider adjusting `WHERE` condition accordingly where *ID* is the unique table ID field which matches the bound field of combobox.

```
Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE [ID] = [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"

Forms("fResultsCases").Recalc
Forms("fResultsCases").Form.Requery   ' USUALLY THE RECORDSOURCE UPDATE CALL
```

Comment: I think I get your point. I tried with replacing with this line:

Forms("fResultsCases").RecordSource = "SELECT * FROM tCases WHERE [case number] = [Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee];"

as  [case number] is the primary key in this table. Got the same result though.

Comment: If I replace with this line:   SELECT tEmployee.surname
FROM tEmployee
WHERE (((tEmployee.surname)=[Forms]![fSearches]![cEmploee]));   It does return the right employee but it returns a single record from tEmployee which is not what I want.
Is there a way to combine this result with tCases too? Also if I changed the primary key in tEmployee to be the surname field, would it help?